# No connection made on subscriber side in rabbitmq server

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, stomp

I setup a Rabbitmq server and trying to publish and subscribe live video streaming using STOMP protocol with topic exchange. I am able to publish the video streaming by establishing the connection in rabbitmq server but not able to subscribe on the other end. Both the codes are provided below

Publisher.py

```
import stomp
import sys
import time
import cv2

conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61613)])
conn.start()
conn.connect('guest', 'guest', wait=True)

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),90]

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if ret is True:
        # Make image smaller for faster delivery
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.6, fy=0.6)
        # Encode into JPEG
        result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)         
        conn.send(body=imgencode.tobytes(), content_type 
         ='image/jpeg',destination='/queue/test')
    time.sleep(0.001)

capture.release()
conn.disconnect()
```

Subscriber.py

```
class MyListener(object):
    def on_error(self, message):
        print ('recieved an error %s' % message)

    def on_message(self, body, message):
        print(type(message))
        print ('recieved a message %s' % message)

       # get the original jpeg byte array size
       # body = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
        size = sys.getsizeof(str.encode(message)) - 33       
        # jpeg-encoded byte array into numpy array
        np_array = np.frombuffer(str.encode(message), dtype=np.uint8)   
        np_array = np_array.reshape((size, 1))
        # decode jpeg-encoded numpy array 
        image = cv2.imdecode(np_array, 1)

        # show image
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        # send message ack
        message.ack()

conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61613)], 'user', 'password')
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.start()
conn.connect(username="guest", password="guest")

conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/test', id = 1,ack='auto')

while True:
    pass
conn.disconnect()
```

I initially receive a message on command prompt as shown below and then Exception with error message. Assertion error means that it has not received any image but then what kind of message is shown below

OUTPUT RECEIVED:

recieved a message ���N����./4�����",��ۂpz�w���T�?� ֮YQ��:cZ��S�jR�   ,Ǧ{k  (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� ��

Exception in thread StompReceiverThread-1:

File "video_sub_stomp.py", line 26, in on_message
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this question...Thanks in advance

Comment: Please someone help me with this query.. I cannot ask further question